# Creating a module with custom database table, cannot save

Tags: magento-1.9, module, database, model

I have developed a custom module that also has a custom database table.
However, I cannot insert records since I am presented with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on boolean in /httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php on line 6105
```

Here is the code that I am trying:

```
$data = array(
          'voucher'     => 'voucher',
          'customer_name' => 'customer_name',
          'order'           => 'order',
          'value'           => 'value',
          'status'      => 1,
          'date'            => '',
        );
$model = Mage::getModel('antikatavoles/antikatavoles')->setData($data);
```

And this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>

<modules>
    <ID_Antikatavoles>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ID_Antikatavoles>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <antikatavoles>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ID_Antikatavoles</module>
                <frontName>antikatavoles</frontName>
            </args>
        </antikatavoles>
    </routers>
</frontend>  
<global>
    <models>
        <antikatavoles>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>antikatavoles_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </antikatavoles>
        <antikatavoles_mysql4>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <antikatavoles>
                    <table>antikatavoles</table>
                </antikatavoles>
            </entities>
        </antikatavoles_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <antikatavoles_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>ID_Antikatavoles</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_setup>
        <antikatavoles_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_write>
        <antikatavoles_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </antikatavoles_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <antikatavoles>
            <class>ID_Antikatavoles_Helper</class>
        </antikatavoles>
    </helpers>
</global>

</config>
```

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

thanks!

Comment: you should disable the Magento compiler when you install a new module

Answer (score 1):

You have compilation mode turned on but the module doesn't have the src compiled for compilation mode.

Also, remove the mysql4 deprecated since 2010 stuff lol

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like below

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$model = Mage::getModel('student/student')->setData(); 
$data = array('name'=>$post['name'],
                         'gender'=>$post['gender'],
                         );
$model->setData($data);
$model->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You have compilation mode turned on.
2. Stop it and re-compile it.

We should not use compilation mode in development.

Comment: who down voted this ? what is wrong in this answer ?